# How to use the same element name for different purposes ( in XML and DTD )?

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I Want to create a DTD schema for this xml document:

```
<root>

    <student>
        <name>
            <firstname>S1</firstname>
            <lastname>S2</lastname>
        </name>
    </student>

    <course>
        <name>CS101</name>
    </course>

</root>
```

as you can see , the element `name` in the `course` contains plain text ,but the element `name` in the `student` is complex type ( first-name, last-name ). The following is the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT root (course|student)*>

<!ELEMENT student (name)>
<!ELEMENT name (lastname|firstname)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT course (name)>
```

When I want to validate it , I get an error because the course's `name` has different structure then the student's `name` .

**My Question:**

- how can I make a work-around solution for this situation without changing the name of element `name` using **DTD not xml schema .**

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry! That's one of the major limitations of DTD: a given element name always has the same content model.

About all you can do is give up on full validation for that particular element, and allow all possible contents:

```
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA|lastname|firstname)*>
```

Comment: Thanks @bobince , I'll use what you wrote as a work-around ,it's easier then XML-schema .

Comment: When using PCDATA this is the best you can do, but if all three possibilities are elements you can get slightly better results.  Consider element `<p>`.  Element `<p>` may contain either element `<a>`, or elements `<b>` and `<c>`.  We can specify this, it just won't be contextual (ie, dependant of `<p>`'s parent).  `<!ELEMENT p (a | (b, c))>`.  PCDATA has to be used as mixed content or all by itself; it can't be an either/or situation, unfortunately.